# why use translation strings instead of the object itselft?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

Going through https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n and https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js  it`s a pretty common approach to have a locales file with a translate function like i18n.t('string'), and multiple translation files, using the received string to find the proper translations

ie (from i18n-js):

```
I18n.t("some.scoped.translation");
// or translate with explicit setting of locale
I18n.t("some.scoped.translation", { locale: "fr" });
```

Well, why instead of using those string paths, don't we just access the translate JSON directly?
it would still be possible to use the i18N lib to get the user language and even set it, but instead of using .t() method, we could just redirect to the proper translation object.
Wouldn't it help avoid typos since you will use the object itself to verify the path?

it seems like a so well diffused practice to use the locales string, I feel like I'm missing something about my approach, but couldn`t get to what it might be, I considered that it would be a heavier duty to go through the whole strings data, but i18n.t() would still have to do it plus parse the string into object path

Comment: "*instead of using .t() method, we could just redirect to the proper translation object.*" that's basically what `.t()` does - it forwards your request for translation to the correct object. In order to spare you having to do the same. "*Wouldn't it help avoid typos since you will use the object itself to verify the path?*" how would that help? Presumably you still want to access something in the form of `a.b.c` - whether you use the actual object or not, if the path is missing you still don't access anything. At least `.t()` has fallbacks and other mechanisms in place.

Comment: well, when using the object directly, you get access to its keys automatically with your editor and an instant warning if your key does not match the language object

I see how .t()'s fallbacks will be helpful but at the cost of verifying your keys in real-time... maybe it`s useful to avoid code-breaking in case a wrong key in the translated object gets deleted? basically sacrificing  a type-check for a try-catch